# Getting Protocol violation error while sqoop import from oracle to hive

Tags: oracle, sqoop

I am trying to import data from oracle to hive through sqoop import command.But i am getting java.sql.SQLexception-protocol violation error. I checked found 1 text column with length(4000).
So i removed that column and ran the sqoop command its working.

So i found that because of that column only i am getting that protocol violation error.

Is this because of the length or something else.
Can someone help me on solving this.Below is the sqoop command i am using

sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@:port/servicename--username --password --query "select *from table_name where $CONDITIONS" --hive-drop-import-delims --target-dir /user/test --map-column-java -m 1

Comment: Hi @sri Laitha , Can you provide a description of the table in Oracle and Hive ? There are unsupported data types between both.

Comment: Hi Roberto....In oracle the column data type is varchar2(4000)  and in hive it is of external table with String datatype

Comment: Hi @sri Laitha. Well, I know of several bugs in the Oracle JDBC driver for Sqoop. Which database version are you connecting to ? Which version of JDBC ?  Whcih sqoop version are you using ?